# Converter DateTime para Date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, linq

Preciso comparar um date sem o horário, somente `("dd/MM/yyyy")` com o banco de dados com `Linq`, porém não estou conseguindo transformar do formato `DateTime("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:s")` para `Date("dd/MM/yyyy")`?

Comment: cadê o código ?

Comment: Você usa Entity Framework?

Comment: Adicione mais informações, como o código. Mas publiquei a resposta e veja se é isso. Qualquer coisa atualizo.

Comment: Relacionado: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.entityfunctions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Relacionado: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Para isso, basta você fazer o seguinte: pegar apenas a data do objeto DateTime.

Exemplo:

```
DateTime apenasData = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

ele vai colocar a hora como 0.

Assim, para usar o linq, você pode utilizar:

```
 resultado = lista.Where(x => x.DataComparada.Date <= dataComparar.Date);
```

Comment: Dependendo da versão isso funciona dependendo não funciona ... !!!

Comment: Se ele tiver usando Linq to Entities, realmente.

Comment: Só coloquei mesmo como observação @Rodrigo !!!

Comment: Mas com o .Date ele irá comparar este valor: '24/10/2018 00:00:00', porém estou precisando que ele pegue este: '24/10/2018'

Comment: Pelo que entendi na pergunta a ideia seria comparar. O tipo date não existe no C#. Quando você bota as horas como 0, você pode comparar normalmente. Mas se quiser você pode pegar isso como uma string, entende? Apenas convertendo data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"). Esse código que eu postei na resposta converte as horas para 00:00 dos dois comparáveis.

Comment: Entendi, convertendo para string eu conheço, a dúvida era realmente se é possível pegar um tipo Date sem o horário("dd/MM/yyyy") mas sem converter para string, porque quando estou montando o meu Linq, por incrível que pareça, se eu passar sem o horário, a consulta fica quase 1 segundo mais rápida